# RTC Video PnP Listener

Tags: video, pnp

This program sometimes prevents my Win10 Creators Update PC from shutting down making me force close it by pressing "shut down anyway". I tried searching for it but no luck. Quite a few people had a similar issue but no definitive answer on what is it and where does it come from. Anyone knows?

I searched the internet and some people say it's from Skype and some say it's a virus. Still no decent answer.

Comment: Same issue for me, just noticed this on shutdown but can't locate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a name for a window object initialized by Skype and Lync. It looks like it listens for video events from Skype/Lync. Run the windows module in Volatility on a Windows 10 memory dump with Lync running, and you will likely get the window object listed in the results.

Comment: Given the conflicting rumors about this program, can you provide an *authoritative* reference for your statement?

Answer (score 0):

I used spy++ to view running processes & threads.  I found a match under "MS Teams":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEJaG.png)

Answer (score -1):

According to Microsoft community and Internet, It seems that this is kind of program that uses the webcam. Somebody said that :

> it stands for Real Time Capturing video Protection and Privacy
>   Listener, which captures your browsing habits and records video from
>   your webcam when you boot your PC to the time you shut down and uploads it to people on the internet for money

Another user wrote that:

> At first I thought that "RTC" might have been Skype related until
>   someone got a hold of my credit card... and these weird accounts with
>   the same username have been finding me on totally unrelated and
>   unlinked sites.

Hence, This is not something you want on your computer, so I would suggest uninstalling it immediately.

Comment: The problem is that there is no evidence to any of these claims. Antiviruses and various malware scanners aren't finding anything. Also this thing is really elusive and I was unable to find anything called "RTC Video PnP Listener" using Apps&Features, Autoruns and other programs. It's seemingly untraceable when you try to search for it.

Comment: To make sure is RTC virus or not, you can use tools like Process Explorer:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer
 launch process explorer as admin, click options in top left, confirm that check signatures is enabled, then click virustotal section, make sure check virustotal is checked, check submit unknown executables, then look for that process and see if it is flagged on virustotal via the blue number.

Comment: I did all that, it's not on the list. Trust me, this thing is not easy to track down.

Comment: Okey @keklord :) I give up, but maybe you can locate and delete the RTC from registry.

Comment: @Emad the quote you posted in its entirety says >it stands for Real Time Capturing video Protection and Privacy Listener, which captures your browsing habits and records video from your webcam when you boot your PC to the time you shut down and uploads it to people on the internet for money. **I just made that up...** Full Link: https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/767166-what-is-rtc-video-pnp-listener/

Comment: @Emad It is also best practice to `Provide a link to the original page or answer` when quoting material. Please refer to https://superuser.com/help/referencing for more information.